# How do I install Minecraft Forge for Windows 8.1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-forge

I just bought a new gaming laptop, the ASUS Republic of Gamers series, built to be all beefy for my gaming needs.

I am trying to add mods for Minecraft but when I try to download Minecraft Forge, it doesn't open up like it should. I've done it on other computers and it works fine but I believe it's because I have Windows 8.1 and I have no idea what I am doing.

What should I do and how do I get Forge and mods for Minecraft?

Comment: Is Java installed?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Forge on Windows 8.1 shouldn't be any different from installing on most other operating systems or versions.

The Windows installer for Forge is at http://files.minecraftforge.net/ (if a direct download link is more useful, [here](http://adfoc.us/serve/sitelinks/?id=271228&url=http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.8-11.14.2.1433/forge-1.8-11.14.2.1433-installer-win.exe)). Once you have the .exe file downloaded, run it, and follow all the directions. It will automatically install Forge for 1.8, and add a `mods` folder to your .minecraft directory.

If you mean by "won't open up like it should" that the installer file doesn't run properly, you may want to make sure your browser or something else isn't blocking the file from downloading or running. After you've installed Forge, the only other thing you need to open is Minecraft. If Minecraft won't open, it could be because of a variety of things- you could have incompatible mods or versions, or some other problem altogether.

If you're being prompted to open something other than Minecraft or the installer, you might want to make sure you have a legitimate Forge download- again, [here](http://adfoc.us/serve/sitelinks/?id=271228&url=http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.8-11.14.2.1433/forge-1.8-11.14.2.1433-installer-win.exe).